# Text is on the middle instead of in the left

Tags: php, html

Why is this in the middle of the textbox? It's probably really simple but I cant figure it out

```
<div class="wrap-input100 bg1">
    <span class="label-input100">Mensagem (Editável)</span>
    <textarea id='mensagem' style="height:200px;" class="input100" type="text" name="mensagem"> 
        <?php 
        $time = date("H");
        $timezone = date("e");
        if ($time < "12") {
            echo "Bom Dia";
        } else if ($time >= "12" && $time < "17") {
            echo "Boa Tarde";
        } else if ($time >= "19") {
            echo "Boa Noite";
        }
        ?> 
    </textarea>
</div>
```

The problem it's not from the class because I deleted it and it was in the middle anyway

[image]

Comment: Could be a global / element CSS style. Nothing to do with PHP though as far as I can see.

Comment: Give the style text-align:left

Comment: fyi, `<textarea>` doesn't have/need `type="text"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have whitespace in your `HTML`. This is accounted for in the textarea.
A solution would be to store the output in a variable and remove the whitespace e.g.

```
<?php 
    $time = date("H");
    $timezone = date("e");
    $output = '';
    if ($time < "12") {
        $output = "Bom Dia";
    } else if ($time >= "12" && $time < "17") {
        $output = "Boa Tarde";
    } else if ($time >= "19") {
        $output = "Boa Noite";
    }
?> 
<textarea id='mensagem' style="height:200px;" class="input100" name="mensagem"><?php echo $output; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: missing closing php tag

Comment: Ah yes, nice spot. Updated

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrap-input100 bg1">
    <span class="label-input100">Mensagem (Editável)</span>
    <?php 
        $time = date("H");
        $timezone = date("e");
        if ($time < "12") {
            $text = "Bom Dia";
        } else if ($time >= "12" && $time < "17") {
            $text = "Boa Tarde";
        } else if ($time >= "19") {
            $text = "Boa Noite";
        }
        ?> 
    <textarea id='mensagem' style="height:200px;" class="input100" name="mensagem"><?= $text ?></textarea>
</div>
```

Try this

Comment: No problem. But DarkBee answered before me

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
<textarea id='mensagem' style="height:200px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;" class="input100" type="text" name="mensagem">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to span tag. Use div instead of tag and add css. See this

```
<div class="wrap-input100 bg1">
    <div class="label-input100" style="float:left; margin-right: 5px;">Mensagem (Editável)</div>
    <textarea id='mensagem' class="input100" style="height:200px; width:40% " type="text" name="mensagem"> 
        <?php 
        $time = date("H");
        $timezone = date("e");
        if ($time < "12") {
            echo "Bom Dia";
        } else if ($time >= "12" && $time < "17") {
            echo "Boa Tarde";
        } else if ($time >= "19") {
            echo "Boa Noite";
        }
        ?> 
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to inspect it on page. Right click on Bom Dia and click on inspect element then check why it is in centre. May be it is because of you class input 100 or it is because of textarea style . you need to modify it's css accordingly.

Comment: check other answers